# Annotation member which holds other annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

I want to create a custom annotation (using Java) which would accept other annotations as parameter, something like:

```
public @interface ExclusiveOr {
    Annotation[] value();
}
```

But this causes compiler error "invalid type for annotation member".

Object[] also doesn't work.

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I myself hereby propose a workaround for the given problem:

Well, what I wanted to make possible was something like that:

```
@Contract({
    @ExclusiveOr({
        @IsType(IAtomicType.class),
        @Or({
            @IsType(IListType.class),
            @IsType(ISetType.class)
        })
    })
})
```

Proposed workaround:

Define a class with parameter-less constructor (which will be called by your own annotation processor later) in following way:

```
final class MyContract extends Contract{
    // parameter-less ctor will be handeled by annotation processor
    public MyContract(){
        super(
            new ExclusiveOr(
                new IsType(IAtomicType.class),
                new Or(
                    new IsType(IListType.class),
                    new IsType(ISetType.class)
                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

usage:

```
@Contract(MyContract.class)
class MyClass{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Because annotations do not accept any type of parameters.
Java allows only to specify an array of ONE CERTAIN type of annotation (not any type, what I need).

Comment: Using the class annotation member inspired my own answer.

Answer (score 6):

The error is produced because you can't use interfaces as annotation values (change it to `Comparable` and you'll get the same error). From the [JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.6):

> It is a compile-time error if the return type of a method declared in an annotation type is any type other than one of the following: one of the primitive types, `String`, `Class` and any invocation of `Class`, an enum type, an annotation type, or an array of one of the preceding types. It is also a compile-time error if any method declared in an annotation type has a signature that is override-equivalent to that of any `public` or `protected` method declared in class `Object` or in the interface `annotation.Annotation`.

I'm afraid I don't know of a good workaround, but now at least you know why you get the error.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the reason why you would want to specify other annotations there are multiple solutions:

### An array of instances of a single annotation type

Probably not what you meant in your question, but if you want to specify multiple instances of a single annotation type it's certainly possible:

```
public @interface Test {
    SomeAnnotation[] value();
}
```

### An array of annotation types instead of instances

If you do not need to specify any parameters on the individual annotations you can just user their class objects instead of instances.

```
public @interface Test {
    Class<? extends Annotation>[] value();
}
```

But an enum would of course also do the trick in most situations.

### Use multiple arrays

If the set of possible annotation types you want to use is limited, you can create a separate parameter for each one.

```
public @interface Test {
    SomeAnnotation[] somes() default { };
    ThisAnnotation[] thiss() default { };
    ThatAnnotation[] thats() default { };
}
```

Giving a default value to each member makes it possible to only specify arrays for the types you need.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
Class<? extends Annotation>[] value();
```

Not sure if that helps, but . . .

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't. I need instances of annotations, not types.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this exact problem, but (inspired by @ivan_ivanovich_ivanoff) I have discovered a way to specify a bundle of ***any*** combination of Annotations as an annotation member: use a prototype / template class.

In this example I define a **WhereOr** (i.e. a "where clause" for my model annotation) which I need to contain arbitrary Spring meta-annotations (like @Qualifier meta-annotations).

The minor (?) defect in this is the forced dereferencing that separates the implementation of the where clause with the concrete type that it describes.

```
@Target({})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface WhereOr {
    Class<?>[] value() default {};
}

@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface JsonModel {
    Class<?> value();
    WhereOr where() default @WhereOr;
}

public class Prototypes {
    @Qualifier("myContext")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR')")
    public static class ExampleAnd {
    }
}

@JsonModel(
        value = MusicLibrary.class,
        where = @WhereOr(Prototypes.ExampleAnd.class)
)
public interface JsonMusicLibrary {
    @JsonIgnore
    int getMajorVersion();
    // ...
}
```

I will programmatically extract the possible valid configurations from the "where clause" annotation. In this case I also use the prototypes class as a logical AND grouping and the array of classes as the logical OR.