# Which types can be used for Java annotation members?

Tags: java, annotations

Today I wanted to create my first annotation interface following [this documentation](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/annotations.html) and I got this compiler error

> ```
> Invalid type for annotation member":
> public @interface MyAnnotation {
>     Object myParameter;
>     ^^^^^^
> }
> ```

Obviously `Object` cannot be used as type of an annotation member. Unfortunately I could not find any information on which types can be used in general.

This I found out using trial-and-error:

- `String` → Valid
- `int` → Valid
- `Integer` → Invalid (Surprisingly)
- `String[]` → Valid (Surprisingly)
- `Object` → Invalid

Perhaps someone can shed some light on which types are actually allowed and why.

Comment: possibly it varies by annotation - please show the code you're trying to write.

Comment: Added to the question. But I don't think it varies.

Answer (score 401, accepted):

It's specified by [section 9.6.1 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1). The annotation member types must be one of:

- primitive
- String
- an Enum
- another Annotation
- java.lang.Class
- an array of any of the above

It does seem restrictive, but no doubt there are reasons for it.

Also note that multidimensional arrays (e.g. `String[][]`) are implicitly forbidden by the above rule.

Comment: How does one find those pages/documents? I swear I google everytime before asking on StackOverlow and on many Java question someone posts a link to the JSL which answers my question. Why do I not find those pages via Google?!

Comment: The JLS isn't very google-friendly. You just need to know that it's there.

Comment: the same information is also available in the annotation guide on sun's site (did find that googling): http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html

Comment: Yes, I found that page, too, but I've must have missed that sentence, hidden in all that prose text. I've looked for something more table or list-like.

Comment: What's missing from the above list is "Annotation".  You can have an annotation which contains another annotation or an array of another annotation.

Comment: Indeed, "annotation" was missing from the list.

Comment: Perhaps not literally "Annotation", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679177/annotation-member-which-holds-other-annotations

Comment: Note that "Class" here is mean to be the literal _java.lang.Class_ class, not all classes.

Comment: Can I have an annotation member of type java.util.function.Function?

Answer (score 42):

Also don't forget that **annotations themselves can be part of an annotation definition**. This allows some simple annotation nesting - handy in cases where you would like to have one annotation present many times.

For example:

```
@ComplexAnnotation({
    @SimpleAnnotation(a="...", b=3),
    @SimpleAnnotation(a="...", b=3),
    @SimpleAnnotation(a="...", b=3)
})
public Object foo() {...}
```

where `SimpleAnnotation` is

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface SimpleAnnotation {
    public String a();
    public int b();
)
```

and `ComplexAnnotation` is

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface ComplexAnnotation {
    public SimpleAnnotation[] value() default {};
)
```

Examples taken from: http://web.archive.org/web/20131216093805/https://blogs.oracle.com/toddfast/entry/creating_nested_complex_java_annotations

*(original URL: https://blogs.oracle.com/toddfast/entry/creating_nested_complex_java_annotations)*

Comment: With Java 8 `@Repeatable`, this is not needed anymore.

Comment: Strictly, `@Repeatable` means that the compiler can build that for you.

Answer (score 15):

The concept of annotations fits really well with the design of my project, until I realized you can't have complex datatypes in the annotation. I got around it by using the class of what I wanted to instantiate rather than an instantiated object of that class. It's not perfect, but java rarely is.

```
@interface Decorated { Class<? extends PropertyDecorator> decorator() }

interface PropertyDecorator { String decorate(String value) }

class TitleCaseDecorator implements PropertyDecorator {
    String decorate(String value)
}

class Person {
    @Decorated(decorator = TitleCaseDecorator.class)
    String name
}
```

Comment: What target type did you use on @interface Decorated ? Tried to use this pattern in my project, everything compiles but at runtime i get a big fat null pointer on "String name" (in my case: List<SomeStuff> myList (trying to decorate a generic processor with a list of things it needs to do to process something)

Answer (score 2):

According to Oracle the valid types for annotation elements are:

```
1. Primitives (byte, char, int, long float, double)
2. Enums
3. Class (Think generics here Class <?>, Class<? extends/super T>>)
4. String
5. Array of the above (array[] of primitives, enums, String, or Class)
5. Another annotation.
```

A plus to note, all elements are inherently considered public and abstract.

Therefore

```
 static final variable(s) allowed as well.
```