# How to Inject values from a property file into JSR Custom Annotation

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations, bean-validation

I have a spring component that validates the values of an Entity Class,

One of the variables has a Custom Annotation whose values are supposed to be loaded from the property file, currently it says that `Attribute must be constant`

Here is the sample code.

I know that Spring allows to fetch properties like this

```
@Value("${allowedNames}")
    private String names;
```

But I have an entity with one of the variables annotated by custom validator interface i.e. `@NameValidationDefinition`. I would like to pass the values from the properties file to the annotation but it gives compile time error that Attribute must be Constant which I understand as I know that

> ```
> Annotations take only constants or final and static declared primitives or Strings
> ```

```
public Class Person {
@NameValidationDefinition(values = names)
private String name;
}
```

What I want to know is that is there a workaround for this to make it work?

The value from the properties file is by default casted to String but still when I create the Entity and initialize the variable as static final and pass the String in the Constructor, I get the same compile time error.

I would appreciate any kind of help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have variables in annotations. That's not a limitation of Bean Validation, but of the JVM itself. See also [Which types can be used for Java annotation members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458535/which-types-can-be-used-for-java-annotation-members)

Note, in the Spring example you are giving the value is a string with a special "key" *${allowedNames}* which later on gets interpolated. That's different from the value of the annotation being an actual variable as your code implies.

Comment: I hear you, and I am aware that anything but constants cannot ne passed to annotations but I was thinking if there was a hacky way of doing it. I mean developers bend the rules all the time with the code.

Comment: No, not on this one. You would have to temper with the JLS itself. Not saying that it cannot be done, but I for sure would not like to go there.

Comment: Haha, got you.. Thanks.. I guess I can mark this as an answer as it might help some else looking for this.