# How do I pass a method to an annotation using Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, annotations

I would like to pass a method to an annotation. Is something like this possible?

```
@MyAnnotation(method = MyClass::myMethod)
private String myVariable;
```

Comment: No: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458535/which-types-can-be-used-for-java-annotation-members

Comment: Hopefully this becomes supported someday. It is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: According to Brian Goetz the implementation efforts are hindering progress on that feature http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2018-November/056596.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Passing a method isn't an option. Instead, pass the following which should allow you to find the method using reflection.

```
@MyAnnotation(clazz=String.class, method="contains", params= {CharSequence.class})

@interface MyAnnotation {
   Class<?> clazz();
   String method();
   Class<?>[] params() default {};
}

MyAnnotation annotation = // get the annotation
annotation.clazz().getMethod(annotation.method(), annotation.params());
```

Comment: Note that annotations allow to omit the braces for single elements arrays, so you may write `params=CharSequence.class` in your example use case. To simplify the no-argument case (even further), I’d use `Class<?>[] params() default {};` in the annotation type declaration, so you can write, e.g. `@MyAnnotation(clazz=String.class, method="isEmpty")`.

Comment: Alternatively, in order to avoid the risk of mistyping `"contains"`, `@interface MyAnnotation` can have a field `Class<? extends Function<String, String>> value()` if you are willing to have one (potentially nested) class per function and use reflection to instantiate the function.

Answer (score 5):

[JSL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.16.1-130) says:

> the annotation attributes only can takes: `byte`, `char`, `double`, `float`, `int`, `long`, `short`, `boolean`, `String`, `Enum` type, `Class`, `Annotation`, 1 dimension array type`[type`.

but a method reference expression must be assigned to a functional interface. so you can't refer a method reference expression at present.