# How to reference a method or property in Java?

Tags: java, hibernate, properties, reference

I am rather new to Java. I'd like to know if it's possible to reference a method or property in Java. This is not specific to Hibernate ORM but just to give you an idea, the following example is written as Hibernate entity classes.

```java
@Entity(name = "Person")
public static class Person {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity(name = "Book")
public static class Book {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @NaturalId
    private String isbn;

    @ManyToOne
    private Person author;
}
```

The `Person::books` property has an `OneToMany` annotation with `mappedBy` set to `"author"`, which eventually references the `Book::author` property at compile time. I believe this is possible thanks to Java's powerful reverse-engineering features a.k.a `Reflection`. This is great, but to make things even easier and debuggable, instead of putting a **String** value as the `mappedBy` value, I would like to use put a reference to the `Book::author`. This will ensure we're not referencing an invalid property on the fly (IDE-friendly). If we change the string to `"authors"` by mistake we would not know it's invalid unless we compile the code.

So the preferred code for the `OneToOne` annotation would look like this:

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = Book::author)
private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
```

I believe method referencing exists in **Objective-C**. (and **JavaScript** too in a hacky way).

As I said, the question is if Java has a method/property referencing feature or any hacks to do this? It's not specific to Hibernate ORM. I am talking about a language feature in general.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291122/how-do-i-pass-a-method-to-an-annotation-using-java-8/44291888

Comment: @Amerousful Thanks for your answer. So you're saying there is no way to do this ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because annotations only allow certain types such as primitives, enums, class, other annotations, [etcetera](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1). They do not allow for interfaces let-alone Function/Method references.

Comment: Is that possible outside of annotations? @json

Comment: @liberia Yes, it would be possible using Reflection. Why you would want this is beyond me. No need to over engineer.