# How to use custom code in Java annotations

Tags: java, annotations, metadata

I have a question about Java Annotations. Is there a way to use code in their usages? It's obvious that I can't use objects but maybe static methods or some other way? I mean something like

```
@Query(MyClass.staticMethod())
```

Of course I had tried above code and it is not working :(
Do anyone have idea how to achieve such thing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call method inside annotation in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49277478/call-method-inside-annotation-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call a method to get a value for the annotation.

Please have look at these posts:
[Java Annotations values provided in dynamic manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636201/java-annotations-values-provided-in-dynamic-manner)

[Which types can be used for Java annotation members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458535/which-types-can-be-used-for-java-annotation-members)