# Enum type as annotation parameter?

Tags: java, class, types, enums, annotations

How can I make my frameworks `MyAnnotation` have a user-defined enum type as the parameter?

Like `@MyAnnotation(Colors.BLUE)`. Another, less idea solution would be `@MyAnnotation(Colors.BLUE.getName())`.

**Edit:** as in the enum is user-specified. I tried `Enum<?> value()`, but that didn't work

Comment: You're allowed to use constants as parameters. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458535/which-types-can-be-used-for-java-annotation-members

Answer (score 0):

You can supply your enum element explicitly when defining the annotation for the relevant type.

```java
enum MyEnum {
    MY_ELEMENT
}
```

```java
@interface MyAnnotation {

    MyEnum value();

}
```

```
@MyAnnotation(value = MyEnum.MY_ELEMENT)
class MyClass {
    
}
```

Comment: but the enum should be user-defined, so the annotation should not know about MyEnum