# How can I supply a symbol to a Java annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

It looks like my misconceptions have led me to this question. Please help me sort them out. JLS 9.6.1 states that "Class or an invocation of Class (§4.5)" is covered as an annotation type, chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic pointed out.

We all agree that a static import is a constant (well, pretend I did not make that statement: It is of course not true https://stackoverflow.com/a/9083023/1236128)

```
import static path.to.someFunction
```

I create an annotation like this

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
public @interface Testing {
    Class<? extends Function> symbol();
}
```

Given a static function (even declaring this final does not make `someFunction` constant by definition in Java, which is throwing me off):

```
public static Function<Long, Long> someFunction = a -> b;
```

Excuse me (I realize there is a difference between the *function* itself and its *application*),

```
public static Function<Long, Long> someFunction = a -> 2L;
```

I create a unit test like this (assuming the aforementioned static import):

```
@Test
@Testing(symbol = someFunction)
void someFunctionTest() {
    ....
}
```

Aside from my mistakes, does anybody recognize how useful this would be at compile time? I could use reflection on all functions marked with say `@Tested` to see whether there is indeed a test for it somewhere (on the basis of the `@Testing` annotation).

The funny thing is, I am supplying the annotation with a constant, but that is the complaint given by IntelliJ:

> Attribute value must be [a] constant.

What's up with that? Is the annotation mechanism trying to execute the function, or will it accept it as a higher order function?

Comment: and [How to supply value to an annotation from a Constant java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065937/how-to-supply-value-to-an-annotation-from-a-constant-java)

Comment: And [Which types can be used for Java annotation members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458535/which-types-can-be-used-for-java-annotation-members)

Comment: I don't agree that a static import is a constant.

Comment: Note: If you _really_ wanted, you could define it as a `String` where you define the lambda's contents, and then compile that `String` to a function instance at runtime when processing the annotation...  Spring's SpEL (amongst other things) work like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We all agree that a static import is a constant.

No, we don't.

A static import does nothing other than making a field/method/... accessible via a simple name as opposed to having to use the fully qualified name.

That simple name might be a reference to a constant field or it might be a reference to something else.

You've defined `someFunction` as

```
public static Function<Long, Long> someFunction = a -> b;
```

According to the rules of the Java language that is not [a "constant expression"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.29) (emphasis mine):

> A constant expression is an expression denoting a value **of primitive type or a String** [...]

Obviously a `Function` is neither a primitive value nor a `String`.

Additionally you've defined the `symbol`  to take a `Class<? extends Function>`, which means you need to assign it a class that implements `Function`. `someFunction` is not a `Class`, it's an actual object that happens to implement `Function`.

Comment: Would applying `final` to my definition of `someFunction` do any good? I have a hard time accepting that `someFunction` is not a constant. Like if I define it as `a->2`.

Comment: @JonathanKomar: would applying `final` change the type to be a primitive or `String`? Would it change the field from `Function` to `Class<? extends Function>`. The short of it is that lambdas won't give you a `Class<? extends Function>`, they can only give you a `Function` so you won't be able to use lambdas in your annotations.

Comment: Ok a couple of things to add to that: I though `Function` was a class. I suppose the application of `someFunction` would be a constant. Would this be covered under Java's def: `Function<Long, Long> someFunction = a -> 2L`? The output could be deboxed into a primitive...

Comment: @JonathanKomar `Function` _is_ a class. You aren't passing `Function.class`, you're trying to pass _an instance of `Function`_.

Answer (score 1):

The overall answer is **no**, you cannot do this. And your code does not work for a multitude of reasons:

- `someFunction` is not a compile time constant
- `someFunction` is not a `Class<? extends Function>` as `symbol` expects
- the actual type `Function<?,?>` is not supported as an attribute type in annotations.

Comment: I was of the understanding that a static function *is* a compile-time constant. Isn't the type `Function<?,?>`just a way of telling the compiler to typecheck `Function` against `?, ?`?

Comment: "constant expression" in Java has a very clear definition and can only ever apply to primitive values or `String` values.

Comment: @JonathanKomar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082971/compile-time-constants-and-variables

Comment: @luk2302 Wow, that post was helpful. msi's answer really hits the nail on the head, and I am prone to think that my question was the result of my misconception of what a *constant* is in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it as-is. [JLS 9.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1):

> The return type of a method declared in an annotation type must be one of the following, or a compile-time error occurs:
>
> - A primitive type
> - String
> - Class or an invocation of Class (§4.5)
> - An enum type
> - An annotation type
> - An array type whose component type is one of the preceding types (§10.1).