# How to inject Set<String> with Annotation-based configuration in Setter Injection?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, setter-injection

I am working on a simple Spring Core project. As we know to work with Spring Core we need to provide some configuration metadata to the IoC Container and the configuration metadata can be supplied in 3 forms. [Source is here](https://github.com/altafjava/spring-interview-questions-answers/tree/core#What-is-Configuration-Metadata)

1. XML-based configuration
2. Java-based configuration
3. Annotation-based configuration

Let's consider an example. I have a class `Team`.

```java
package com.altafjava.bean;
public class Team {
    private String teamName;
    private Set<String> players;

    public void setTeamName(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    public void setPlayers(Set<String> players) {
        this.players = players;
    }
}
```

As we can see it has 2 attributes and we want to inject those values by using `Setter Injection`. We can do this by using `XML-based configuration` as:

```xml
<bean id="team" class="com.altafjava.bean.Team">
        <property name="teamName" value="Avengers" />
        <property name="players">
            <set>
                <value>Iron Man</value>
                <value>Captain America</value>
                <value>Thor</value>
                <value>Hulk</value>
                <value>Thor</value>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

We can also do this by using `Java-based configuration` as:

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public Team team() {
        Team team = new Team();
        team.setTeamName("Football Players");
        Set<String> players = new HashSet<>();
        players.add("Ronaldo");
        players.add("Messi");
        players.add("Salah");
        players.add("Messi");
        team.setPlayers(players);
        return team;
    }
}
```

**Now the question is how can we do this by using `Annotation-based configuration`?**

In Annotation-based configuration generally, we use stereotype annotation like `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Controller`, `@Repository`.

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible since [an annotation cannot contains any type value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458535/which-types-can-be-used-for-java-annotation-members).

Comment: The answer you have given is by using `Java-based configuration` which I already have in my question itself. I need a solution by using `Annotation-based configuration`.

Comment: Then, is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as annotations are used at compile time and since reflection is not compiled...